# Whats the correct format for django dateTime?

Tags: django, datetime

Im writting an app, and im using a datetime selector to allow users to select a date and time. After some formatting in javascript, im left with a dateTime like this:

```
2012-09-04 06:00 PM
```

and django throws and error saying:

```
[u"'2012-09-04 06:00 PM' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
```

Ive also tried

```
2012-09-04 06:00PM
2012-09-04 06:00 P.M.
2012-09-04 06:00P.M.
```

but no luck. Can anyone see what Im doing here? Or know what django is looking for (in English)?

Comment: Do you have a [Django form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/) handling your form? If so, let's see what it looks like.

Comment: No django form, simply using a query string, parsing it, and saving the results to the DB.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As said by the error msg, it expects `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]`, thus following are valid values:

```
2012-09-04 06:00
2012-09-04 06:00:00
2012-09-04 06:00:00.000000

# w/ optional TZ as timezone. 
2012-09-04 06:00Z # utc
2012-09-04 06:00:00+0800
2012-09-04 06:00:00.000000-08:00
```

Comment: Is there anyway to differentiate between am or pm?

Comment: @eastbeast I'm afraid not for the `DateTimeField`

Comment: To be fair to @eastbeast, the error message doesn't provide complete time zone formatting info with the spec `...]][TZ]`. It doesn't specify that "UTC" and "PST" are invalid values for `[TZ]` whereas "Z", "-0800", and "-08:00" are valid values.

Answer (score 3):

After talking around, what I figured out is that there is no AM/PM input. I had to just check if my dateTimePicker was returning an AM or PM suffix, then call time.split(":"); to break up hours and minutes, convert the hours to int from a string, then add 12 to it to convert the time to 24 hour time instead of 12 hour time. Theirs probably an easier way to do it, but thats what worked for me.

For example:

2012-09-04 06:00 PM

Needs to be

2012-09-04 18:00

Answer (score 1):

I used this`'2012-09-04 06:00:00.000000-08:00'` and it worked perfectly