# Validation Error Datetime Format Django

Tags: python, html, django, datetime

I am building this app that keeps track of events and on the edit page I am trying to update_or_create the datetime field.  It's very barebones right now as I just started.

Although I am typing in the right format for the datetime it is telling me that it is in the incorrect format.  How do I format the input from the input field so that it gets accepted as the correct format?

views.py

```
def edit(request, event_id):
if request.method == 'POST':
    name = request.POST['name']
    description = request.POST['description']
    location = request.POST['location']
    date = str(request.POST['date'])
    updated_values = {'name':name, 'location':location, 'date':date, 'description':description}
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=event_id)
    event = Event.objects.update_or_create(name='name', date='date', defaults=updated_values)
    return detail(request, event_id)

else:
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=event_id)
    return render(request, 'events/edit.html', {'event' : event})
```

edit.html (the form)

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'events:edit' event.id %}">
{% csrf_token %}
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <label>Date</label>
  <input type="text" name="date">
  <label>Location</label>
  <input type="text" name="location">
  <label>Description</label>
  <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="description"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is the error stack

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://0.0.0.0:8000/events/edit/3/

Django Version: 1.9
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'website',
 'events.apps.EventsConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/Conner/dev/jivetribe/events/views.py" in edit
  24.         event = Event.objects.update_or_create(name='name', date='date', defaults=updated_values)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  122.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in update_or_create
  480.             obj = self.get(**lookup)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  378.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  790.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  808.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1243.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1269.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1203.             condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_lookup
  1099.                 return final_lookup(lhs, rhs)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in __init__
  19.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in get_prep_lookup
  57.         return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_lookup(self.lookup_name, self.rhs)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_lookup
  744.             return self.get_prep_value(value)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  1440.         value = super(DateTimeField, self).get_prep_value(value)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  1296.         return self.to_python(value)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in to_python
  1423.             params={'value': value},

Exception Type: ValidationError at /events/edit/3/
Exception Value: [u"'date' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
```

EDIT
models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=500, default = 'null')
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

Comment: post the event model code. Think you declared DateTimeField for `date` property.

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255157/whats-the-correct-format-for-django-datetime)

Comment: Yeah I tried copying and pasting one of those examples to see if it would work but it's still throwing that error...