# ["'%(value)s' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."] will show up if I check for full_clean()

Tags: django, validation, datetime, pytz

I am getting the following error when I try to see if my object is valid using `full_clean()`.

```sh
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'schedule_date': ["'%(value)s' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]}
```

I have tried all the formats recommended here, but none of them work for me:

[Whats the correct format for django dateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255157/whats-the-correct-format-for-django-datetime)

I won't get error when I create the object like `Object.objects.create(...)`

Here is my `models.py`:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from userstweetsmanager.constants import LANGUAGE_CHOICES

def password_validator(value):
    if len(value) < 6:
        raise ValidationError(
            str('is too short (minimum 6 characters)'),
            code='invalid'
        )

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    password = models.TextField(validators=[password_validator])
    twitter_api_key = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    twitter_api_secret_key = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    twitter_access_token = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    twitter_access_token_secret = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    expire_date = models.DateField(default=date.today() + timedelta(days=14))
    language = models.TextField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='1')

def schedule_date_validator(value):
    if value < timezone.now() or timezone.now() + timedelta(days=14) < value:
        raise ValidationError(
            str('is not within the range (within 14 days from today)'),
            code='invalid'
        )

def content_validator(value):
    if len(value) > 140:
        raise ValidationError(
            str('is too long (maximum 140 characters)'),
            code='invalid'
        )

class Tweet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(validators=[content_validator])
    schedule_date = models.DateTimeField(validators=[schedule_date_validator])
```

Here is my test code where the error occurs:

```py
    def test_valid_tweet(self):
        owner = User.objects.get(name="Hello")
        tweet = Tweet(user=owner, content="Hello world!", schedule_date=timezone.now())
        try:
            tweet.full_clean() # error occurs here
            pass
        except ValidationError as e:
            raise AssertionError("ValidationError should not been thrown")
        tweet.save()
        self.assertEqual(len(Tweet.objects.all()), 1)
```

As I tested creating an object in the `python manage.py shell`, it will cause error, but if I do `full_clean()`, it will cause error.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the logic of the code. I specified the time range that won't allow even one millionth second difference in the `schedule_date` and `timezone.now()`

After taking a look at the source code of `DateTimeField`, it seems like if I have my validator to throw code="invalid", it will just show the above error message, which made me confused about where my code is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

i solve this problem with this

```
datetime.strptime(request.POST['date'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")
```